# Sentence meaning in a board game

Tags: meaning

Ok so this is a game where each player controlls an explorer, and at a certain time we have to choose a person to became the traitor.

The following is written:

> "Oldest player (not necessarily the oldest explorer)"

In the sentence inside the () does this mean that we have to choose the oldest player (actual person) or we can choose the oldest explorer (in character)?

My doubt is because the sentence makes it (to me at least) seem like its an option not a manditory requirement so speaking in english terms only and ignoring the game rules does this mean we HAVE to pick the oldest player or its an option and we can pick the oldest explorer?

P.S the game is "betrayal at the house of the hill"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.   To me it's crystal clear.  Oldest player, not necessarily the oldest explorer. (It's got to be the oldest player, no matter whether or not they are the oldest explorer.)

Comment: @Centaurus I thought it would be something like.

"Water boils at 100 degrees"

"Not necessarily in different pressure it can boil at different temperatures"

where the not necessarily makes it a condition

Comment: @Centaurus what is the diference between the two?

Comment: You have to pick the oldest (age-wise, real-life) player. That player might or might not be (is not necessarily) controlling the oldest explorer. In other words, don't assume that the age of the explorer indicates the age of the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is the oldest player, regardless of whether their explorer is the oldest or not.

The circumlocution is required because if the oldest player might be controlling the oldest explorer, so they couldn't absolutely eliminate the possibility that the person referred to is the one controlling the oldest explorer.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the reaseaning.
If the oldest player is controlling the oldest explorer in both cases is always him. that would be the ideal situation with no doubt about it. why would the circumlocution be needed in this case

Comment: @TomásPessanha, suppose it said "The oldest player (not the oldest explorer)", then if the oldest player controlled the oldest explorer one part of the rule would say that is the person, and another part would say it's not.